# PHP: take out duplicate digits from an array then print them out

Tags: php, arrays

I'm probably [super]overthinking this. I'm trying to analyze an array with values like [1,9], [4,6] [5,5], [6,4], [9,1] and duplicate digits (I'm having a super brain fart and can't even remember the term for numbers like this) remove (the last two) so that only [1,9], [4,6] [5,5] are printed.

I was thinking that turning this array into a string and using preg_match, but I'm pretty sure this wouldn't work even if I had the correct regex.

Comment: If you always have items in this order, you can take first half +1 of the array. Are you thinking about *palindrom*?

Comment: Something like `unset(sizeof($array));`?

Comment: Is the input static? Will it always have 5 items?

Comment: Will the input always be symmetric? Items are distributed equally on both sides of `[5,5]`. Is it by coincidence?

Comment: @A.L Yes palindrom is the word I was thinking. The [5,5]  one, are results from an earlier a part 9 (these have to equal 10). But yes the main point is getting rid of the Palindroms

Comment: `1946556491` is a palindrom but the `19` and `91` elements are not palindroms, they are reversed strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like elements are distributed symmetrically.

We can cut the array in two halves and get only the first half with [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$array = array(
    array(1,9),
    array(4,6),
    array(5,5),
    array(6,4),
    array(9,1),
);
print_r(array_slice($array, 0, ceil(count($array) / 2)));
```

Result:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 9
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 6
    )
    [2] => Array(
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 5
    )
)
```

[Demo at Codepad](http://codepad.org/uJLxkejd).

[`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) is used to round the number up to the next highest integer if there is an even number of items in the array. Example: if there is 3 items in the array, `5 / 2` will return `2.5`, we want 3 items so we use `ceil(2.5)` which gives `3`.

Example with 3 items:

```
$array = array(
    array(1,9),
    array(5,5),
    array(9,1),
);
print_r(array_slice($array, 0, ceil(count($array) / 2)));
```

Result:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 9
    )

    [1] => Array(
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 5
    )
)
```

Example with 4 items:

```
$array = array(
    array(1,9),
    array(7,7),
    array(7,7),
    array(9,1),
);
print_r(array_slice($array, 0, ceil(count($array) / 2)));
```

Result:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 9
    )

    [1] => Array(
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 7
    )
)
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to detect duplicates dynamically not delete the last 2 elements

Comment: It leaves no room to grow. If you assume that it will always be the same, what happens if you decide to add more? Now you have to go back to the code and recode what you should have coded in the first place.

Comment: @OliverQueen This solution won't work if the OP explain that the distribution can be asymmetric, for now it's a valid solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried the first one, but it wasn't quite what I was looking for. This one was it. I'll have to try and see if this can be expanded. (Which I should have tried before I accepted it, even though it did work.)

Comment: I added some more numbers that would still functioned for my previous work (which isn't shown), and it still works.  Thanks again! I hope this helps someone else who may be over thinking.

Comment: @AmandaIaria As long as the numbers are distributed symmetrically in the array, the code from this answer will work. Otherwise, the answer from Don't Panic will work with any distribution.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an array of pairs like this:

```
$x = array(
    array(1,9),
    array(4,6),
    array(5,5),
    array(6,4),
    array(9,1)
);
```

Here is one way to get the unique pairs:

```
foreach ($x as $pair) {
    sort($pair);
    $unique_pairs[implode(',', $pair)] = $pair;
}
```

This uses string representations of each sorted pair as keys in a new array, so the result will have distinct values by definition.

As far as the printing them out part of your question, once you have the unique values you can loop over them and print them out in whichever format you like, for example:

```
foreach ($unique_pairs as $pair) { vprintf("[%d,%d]<br>", $pair); }
```

Comment: that's cleaner then the heavy duty other answers.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct in understanding what you are trying to do, you want to remove the final 2 elements from the array?

There is a function in PHP called [array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) that removes the final element from the array.

```
$array = array_pop($array);
```

So if you run this twice, you will remove the final 2 elements from the array.

Comment: no... even though the two elements *happen* to be the duplicate ones, op really wants to remove *duplicates*, not the two last entries.

Comment: yeah I wish it was that simple T-T.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it (and I hope **I** am not overthinking this :))

```
$stringArray = array();
$stringArray[] = '1,9';
$stringArray[] = '4,6';
$stringArray[] = '5,5';
$stringArray[] = '6,4';
$stringArray[] = '9,1';

foreach($stringArray as &$numString) {
    $numString = explode(',', $numString);
    usort($numString, function($a, $b) {return $a - $b;});
    $numString = implode(',', $numString);
}


$a = array_unique($a);

print_r($a);
```

You basically explode every element into a subarray, sort it and then implode it back. After calling the `array_unique`, you're left with unique values in the array.

The output would be

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,9
    [1] => 4,6
    [2] => 5,5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The result you suggest treats [a,b] as equivalent to [b,a] which makes the problem a lot more complex. The code below gives the result you asked for, but without really understanding what the problem is that you are trying to fix and whether [1,9] is equivalent to [9,1] in the solution:

```
$a=array(array(1,9),array(4,6),...
$dup=array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($a) -1; $i++) {
   for ($j=$i+1; $j<count($a); $j++) {
      if (($a[$i][0]==$a[$j[0] && $a[$i][1]==$a[$j[1])
         || ($a[$i][0]==$a[$j[1] && $a[$i][1]==$a[$j[0])) {
            $dup[]=$j;
      }
   }
}
foreach ($dup as $i) {
    unset($a[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Boom. If I may suggest, why not just remove it directly within the `if()` statement?

Comment: Because that creates null values which will match an earlier [0,0] unless you replace the == with === . I was aiming for transparency over brevity.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm actually going to assume your question to have a different meaning than everyone else did. I believe what you're asking is:

How do you filter out array items where a reverse of the item has already been used?

```
<?php
// The example set you gave
$numberSets = [[1, 9], [4, 6], [5, 5], [6, 4], [9, 1]];

// Initialize an empty array to keep track of what we've seen
$keys = [];

// We use array filter to get rid of items we don't want
// (Notice that we use & on $keys, so that we can update the variable in the global scope)
$numberSets = array_filter($numberSets, function($set) use(&$keys) {
    // Reverse the array
    $set = array_reverse($set);

    // Create a string of the items
    $key = implode('', $set);

    // Get the reverse of the numbers
    $reversedKey = strrev($key);

    // If the palindrome of our string was used, return false to filter
    if (isset($keys[$reversedKey])) {
        return false;
    }

    // Set the key so it's not used again
    // Since $keys is being passed by reference it is updated in global scope
    $keys[$key] = true;

    // Return true to NOT filter this item, since it or it's reverse were not matched
    return true;

});

var_dump($numberSets);
```